# Post-processing on audio from the iPhone user's music library?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to apply post-processing to audio from an iPhone user's music library (i.e. the iPod app). This could happen in a number of ways:

- Piping the media player's output through an Audio Unit.
- Writing a custom audio output device, and having the media player send audio to it.
- Getting direct access to the files in the user's music library.

Are any of these things possible? I know all of them would be on the desktop, but what about the iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written [some sample code](https://github.com/davidcairns/MediaPlayerDemo) that does just this, which is based on [some code from Chris Adamson](http://www.subfurther.com/blog/2010/12/13/from-ipod-library-to-pcm-samples-in-far-fewer-steps-than-were-previously-necessary/).