# Using Audio Effects with iPhone music library

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, audio, effects

I'm trying to add some audio effects to an iPhone app I'm developing.

The app is a music player that allows users to choose songs from their iTunes music library. I want them to be able to carry some basic adjustments for example Bass, Middle, Treble and perhaps add some reverb. I've played around with NVDSP and looked at audio units however these don't seem to work with the iTunes library due to DRM restrictions.

Has anybody managed to achieve this? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post-processing on audio from the iPhone user's music library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480685/post-processing-on-audio-from-the-iphone-users-music-library)